# Ruby iterating through string

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to iterate through the vowels `"aeiou"` and move every letter forward, returning the string `"eioua"`. This is my code:

```
def vowel(letter)
  vowels = "aeiou"
  string = ""
  index = 0
  while index < letter.length
    current_id = vowels.index(letter)
    next_vowel = vowels[current_id + 1]
    string += next_vowel
    index += 1
  end
  string
end
```

When I pass `"aeiou"` as a parameter to my method, it just takes `"a"`, and prints `"eeeee"`.

```
vowel("aeiou") # => "eeeee"
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always appending the vowel, found by index `current_id = vowels.index(letter)` (increased by one.) That’s why the code appends `e` (the next to `a`) five times. `index` variable is used as a loop counter only.

There is another glitch with this code: when `letter` is the last one, `current_id` is an index of the last letter and `vowels[current_id + 1]` is `nil`.

At the moment I am unable to provide a solution for this problem, because the description and expected result are not consistent: “moving every letter forward” won’t produce `"eioua"` on the given input.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't mean one letter forward- I meant that each vowel would become the next vowel to the right of it so "a" would become "e" and "u" would become "a."  I also noticed that vowels[current_id + 1] becomes nil but I still don't fully understand why can you elaborate?  Thank you for the helpful feedback!

Comment: When `current_id` is an index of the last letter, `current_id + 1` is an index that is greater than string length, that said, it’s an non-existing index. `'abc'[3]` is e.g. `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate the letters of the word (and form a new word, as opposed to modifying the word in place) one way is:

```
str = "aeiou"

new_str = str.chars.rotate.join.   #=> "eioua" 
str                                #=> "aeiou"
```

If you wish to modify the string in place:

```
str.object_id.                     #=> 70128532752540 
str.replace(str.chars.rotate.join) #=> "eioua"
str                                #=> "eioua" 
str.object_id                      #=> 70128532752540
```

Comment: This is a much better way of doing it. Ruby has all these short Enumerator based methods that are really great when they can be used in conjunction.